# How to implement IClassFixture hierarchy in xunit.net

Tags: c#, generics, xunit.net

In xunit.net I'm trying to utilize the same `ConfigFixture` in both  `LogFixture` and `DbFixture`, but to no avail.

Why I'm trying to do this is because I'd like to utilize the same configuration fixture in other fixtures so I can keep class concerns separated, i.e bringing in the config fixture as a building block where needed.

Example:

```
public class Test : IClassFixture<DbFixture>
{
    public Test(DbFixture db)
    {
    }

    [Fact]
    public void MyTest()
    {
        Assert.True(true);
    }
}

public class DbFixture : IClassFixture<LogFixture>, IClassFixture<ConfigFixture>
{
    public DbFixture(LogFixture log, ConfigFixture conf)
    {
        SetupDbConnection(conf.ConnectionString);
        SetupEfLogging(log);
    }
}

public class LogFixture : IClassFixture<ConfigFixture>
{
    public LogFixture(ConfigFixture conf)
    {
        if (conf.IsLoggingEnabled)
            SetupXunitLogging();
    }
}

public class ConfigFixture
{
    public string ConnectionString => Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyDb");
    public bool IsLoggingEnabled => Configuration.GetValue<bool>("EnableLogging");
}
```

Running this code throws this error

> System.AggregateException : One or more errors occurred. (Class fixture type 'MyTests.TestFixtureA' had one or more unresolved constructor arguments: TestFixtureB b, TestFixtureC c) (The following constructor parameters did not have matching fixture data: TestFixtureA a)
> ---- Class fixture type 'MyTests.TestFixtureA' had one or more unresolved constructor arguments: TestFixtureB b, TestFixtureC c
> ---- The following constructor parameters did not have matching fixture data: TestFixtureA a
>
> ----- Inner Stack Trace #1 (Xunit.Sdk.TestClassException) -----
>
> ----- Inner Stack Trace #2 (Xunit.Sdk.TestClassException) -----

How should I setup this to make it work?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem Take a step back and explain **why you think you need this.** What is your underlying problem?

Comment: Updated code to make it more easier to understand what I'm after. Hope it makes my intentions more clear :)

Comment: Ok trying again =)